# Error fetching replies: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "user_2X1db3x0LHntSetxVPnwWBh1ziR" (type string) at path "author" for model "Thread

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am getting the following error when trying to fetch the replies to a user's threads:

Error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "user_2X1db3x0LHntSetxVPnwWBh1ziR" (type string) at path "author" for model "Thread"

Here is the code that I am using:

```
export async function getActivity(userId: string) {
  try {
    connectToDB();

    // Find all threads created by the user
    const userThreads = await Thread.find({ author: userId });

    // Collect all the child thread ids (replies) from the 'children' field of each user thread
    const childThreadIds = userThreads.reduce((acc, userThread) => {
      return acc.concat(userThread.children);
    }, []);

    // Find and return the child threads (replies) excluding the ones created by the same user
    const replies = await Thread.find({
      _id: { $in: childThreadIds },
      author: { $ne: userId }, // Exclude threads authored by the same user
    }).populate({
      path: "author",
      model: User,
      select: "name image _id",
    });

    return replies;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching replies: ", error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your schema for Thread and User. You are trying to find a Thread based on an `author` value of `user_2X1db3x0LHntSetxVPnwWBh1ziR`. If `author` is of type `ObjectId` then `user_2X1db3x0LHntSetxVPnwWBh1ziR` cannot be cast by mongoose to compare against an `ObjectId` value.